# Planarity on $10$ vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there a planar graph on $10$ vertices such that its complement is planar as well?

I have troubles deciding if this is an elementary or deep question. By some other thread, the answer is an easy No for $11$ or more vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every planar graph with nine points has a nonplanar complement, as proven in a paper "Every planar graph with nine points has a nonplanar complement" by Battle et al., which is available [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183524923). Hence the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is no, but I have only an experimental evidence.

$K_{10}$ has 45 edges, and the max number of edges for a planar graph with 10 vertices is $3\cdot10-6=24$.

So the only possible pairs of number of edges are {24, 21} and {23, 22}. I used Brendan McKay's program [plantri](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) to generate all the planar graphs with 24 and 23 edges, and then I used Mathematica to find planar graphs among their complements. I found none, so there is not such a graph with 10 vertices.

By the way, using the same approach I found no such a graph with 9 vertices, but I found many with 8 vertices.

Comment: Cool, is there one on $8$ vertices that easily sticks in mind?

Comment: For example [this one](http://www.numbersaplenty.com/data/plan8.png). Since I'm lazy I selected one graph which is isomorphic to its complement. So one picture instead of two.  Note: the graph is planar, but this drawing of the graph is not...